# Android media player lock screen

Tags: android, lockscreen

I just want to control media player stop/play from lock screen.

I found two ways, RemoteControlClient and Mediasession.
but I don't understand how to use them.
would you show me full source?

How to code MyRemoteControlEventReceiver class in my code?
Actually AudioBackService class has broadcastReceiver.
Is Ok if I use AudioBackservice as MyRemoteControlEventReceive?

RemoteControlClient example code

```
ComponentName myEventReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), MyRemoteControlEventReceiver.class.getName());
 AudioManager myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 myAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(myEventReceiver);
 // build the PendingIntent for the remote control client
 Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
 mediaButtonIntent.setComponent(myEventReceiver);
 PendingIntent mediaPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, mediaButtonIntent, 0);
 // create and register the remote control client
 RemoteControlClient myRemoteControlClient = new RemoteControlClient(mediaPendingIntent);
 myAudioManager.registerRemoteControlClient(myRemoteControlClient);
```

My AudioBackServcie code (media service)

```
public class AudioPlaybackService extends Service implements OnPreparedListener, OnCompletionListener
{
    final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;




    public static final String
            BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_STOP = "stop"
            ;



   MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private String url;

    final BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_STOP)) stopSelf();

        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {

        this.url = "http://c5.inlive.co.kr:4282";
        Log.d("URL", url);

        mediaPlayer.reset();
        try
        {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            showNotification();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {

        super.onCreate();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);





        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_STOP);

        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        stopSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        Log.d("Service", "MediaPlayer prepared. Music will play now.");
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private PendingIntent makePendingIntent(String broadcast)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(broadcast);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    }

    private void showNotification()
    {
        // Create notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(this.url) // audio url will show in notification
                .setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class), 0));
                //.addAction(R.drawable.stop, "Stop", makePendingIntent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_STOP));
        Notification noti =notificationBuilder.build();
        RemoteViews contentiew = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom);
        contentiew.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, makePendingIntent(BROADCAST_PLAYBACK_STOP));
        noti.contentView = contentiew;



        // Show notification
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,noti );
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() // called when the service is stopped
    {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        stopForeground(true);
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

thank you